# Use JavaScript function inside ask_confirmation dialog - Shiny R

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I've this HTML buttons:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
    <option value="item0">--Select an Item--</option>
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>

<select id="size">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>
```

In addition I've also this Java Script function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#type").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "item1") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item2") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item3") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item0") {
            $("#size").html("<option value=''>--select one--</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

I want to put the buttons with the Java script function inside the ask_confirmation dialog
in my Shiny app.

This is my ask_confirmation dialog code:

```
    ask_confirmation(
      "hi",
      title = "hi",
      type = "info", 
      width = '50%',
      html = TRUE,
      text =
        div(HTML(" my html code..
                  ")))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What is `ask_confirmation`? It comes from a package? Which one?

Comment: yes, shinyWidgets packages. It very similar to ShinyAlert, but works better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following.

Put the JS code in a string:

```r
jsfun <- "
var val = $(this).val();
if (val == \"item1\") {
  $(\"#size\").html(
    \"<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>\"
  );
} else if (val == \"item2\") {
  $(\"#size\").html(
    \"<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>\"
  );
} else if (val == \"item3\") {
  $(\"#size\").html(
    \"<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>\"
  );
} else if (val == \"item0\") {
  $(\"#size\").html(\"<option value=''>--select one--</option>\");
}
"
```

And in the `text` argument, put this HTML:

```r
tags$div(
  tags$select(
    tags$option(value = "item0", "Select an item"),
    tags$option(value = "item1"),
    tags$option(value = "item2"),
    tags$option(value = "item3"),
    onchange = jsfun
  ),
  tags$select(
    id = "size",
    tags$option(value = "", "select one")
  )
)
```

---

```r
jsfun <- "
var val = $(this).val();
if (val == \"item1\") {
  $(\"#size\").html(
    \"<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>\"
  );
} else if (val == \"item2\") {
  $(\"#size\").html(
    \"<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>\"
  );
} else if (val == \"item3\") {
  $(\"#size\").html(
    \"<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>\"
  );
} else if (val == \"item0\") {
  $(\"#size\").html(\"<option value=''>--select one--</option>\");
}
"

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    ask_confirmation(
      "hi", 
      text = tags$div(
        tags$select(
          tags$option(value = "item0", "Select an item"),
          tags$option(value = "item1", "item1"),
          tags$option(value = "item2", "item2"),
          tags$option(value = "item3", "item3"),
          onchange = jsfun
        ),
        tags$select(
          id = "size",
          tags$option(value = "", "select one")
        )
      ),
      html = TRUE
    )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you means just to put the second block in the text of ask_confirmation? It doesn't work..

Comment: @asdf1212 Works for me. I edited my answer to add an example.